# Row-wise conjugation of completely bounded map by group action

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, matrix-analysis, group-actions, operator-norms

Let $B$ be a $G$-$C^*$-algebra and let $\phi\colon B \to B$ be a completely bounded map (not necessarily $G$-equivariant). For group elements $F := \{h_1, \ldots, h_k\} \subset G$ we consider the following linear map $\phi_F$ on $M_k(B)$: A matrix $[b_{ij}]_{1 \le i,j \le k}$ is mapped to the matrix $[h_j^{-1}.\phi(h_j.b_{ij})]_{1 \le i,j \le k}$, where the dot denotes the group action.

(That is to say, we first act on the rows of the matrix by the corresponding group elements, then apply the amplification $\phi^{(k)}$ of $\phi$ to $(k\times k)$-matrices, and finally act again on the rows by the inverse group elements.)

We of course have a naive estimate on the operator norm of $\phi_F$ by something like $k \|\phi^{(k)}\|$. My question is now whether we can do better, i.e., whether we can give an estimate independent of $k$?

Comment: No, even if $phi$ is a state on a commutative $G$-C*-algebra $C(X)$. The row matrix $[f_1,\ldots,f_k]$ has norm $1$ if $f_j$'s have disjoint supports and have norm $1$, but one can easily arrange them to satisfy $\phi(h_j\cdot f_j)=1$ for all $j$ and hence the row matrix $[\phi(h_j\cdot f_j)]$ has norm $\sqrt{k}$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! If you make it an answer, I will gladly accept it.